# Why can't I see the mesh after using subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, subdivision-surface

When I use Subdivision surface modifier on that mesh, I can't see the mesh in my viewport. Any ideas or solutions to fix that?

[image: Level 0 subdivided]

[image: Level 1 subdivided]

Comment: I'd probably need to see a wireframe but my guess is that you're missing edges that would stop the mesh from collapsing.

Comment: I suspect Haskell McRavin is right, and the fix for that would be to make sure you don't have Ngons. (the large C-shaped flat side, is it a single face ?)

Comment: I've already read that, can't it be caused by the GPU Subdivision option in Preferences > Viewport > Subdivision?

Comment: I figured out this issue not only in this mesh, so I tried moonboots' solution and it works. but why this happened? Thanks <3

Comment: I can't tell   ^^  I can just tell you that I already saw the question and answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the *GPU Subdivision* option in *Preferences > Viewport > Subdivision*